# Add a black drop shadow to an image through InDesign JavaScript scripting

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-indesign

I am an absolute beginner with JavaScript scripting for InDesign.
I create an object like this:

```
var rectbox = doc.pages.item(0).rectangles.add({geometricBounds:[20,20,70,120]});
var image = rectbox.place(File('/path/image.pdf'));
```

and now I simply want to add a black drop shadow.

Can someone help me?

It seems to me impossible to find some example about. It is incredible...

Many thanks!

Roberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution: if my box contains a filling color, ok, it works; but, if the box contains an image or something else, then I need to use **transparencySettings** instead of **fillTransparencySettings**:

```
var myTransparencySettings = rectbox.transparencySettings;
```

Then

```
var rectbox = doc.pages.item(0).rectangles.add({geometricBounds:[20,20,70,120]});
var image = rectbox.place(File('/path/image.pdf'));
var myTS = rectbox.transparencySettings;
myTS.dropShadowSettings.mode = ShadowMode.drop;
...
```

works perfectly!

Many thanks to Johan, however!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples howto implement a shadow.
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/778309
http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/sdk/cs6/scripting/InDesign_ScriptingGuide_JS.pdf (page 57).

Try this:

```
var rectbox = doc.pages.item(0).rectangles.add({geometricBounds:[20,20,70,120]});
var image = rectbox.place(File('/path/image.pdf'));
var myFillTransparencySettings1 = rectbox.fillTransparencySettings;
myFillTransparencySettings1.dropShadowSettings.mode = ShadowMode.drop;
myFillTransparencySettings1.dropShadowSettings.angle = 90;
myFillTransparencySettings1.dropShadowSettings.xOffset = 0;
myFillTransparencySettings1.dropShadowSettings.yOffset = 0;
myFillTransparencySettings1.dropShadowSettings.size = 6;
```

Comment: Hi, Johan! I tried with your suggestion, but it doesn't work, like some other methods I've found in the documentation you show me. It doesn't give any errors, but simply doesn't produce any shadow, neither changing parameters. It seems there is something wrong... Maybe a bug?

Comment: Probably you need to run the script somehow you can debug it. Try this: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/documentation.html